# Microsoft Office license type MSDN

Tags: microsoft-office, license

Recently I bought a Microsoft Office 2016 Professional license from an local online marketplace in my country. The price was very cheap around 9 US$ if I convert it from my currency to US$.

The seller tells me that I can verify my product key to seapa@microsoft.com (it's an mail based verification, South East Asia Product Activation / SEAPA). Then I did, and the product key does verified to be a genuine and valid.

But the thing is that the license type is MSDN. As far as I know license type are OEM, FPP or volume. I didn't know there are other type of licenses.

Can anyone explain the variety of Microsoft license types? How many license types are they? And what are the differentiation between these license types?

PS. Tried to google about this, but the information about license type MSDN are very unclear.

Comment: All it means that while it's technically valid it's not meant to be sold.